# how to choose between wilcard cert and sub-domain cert in apache

Tags: linux, apache

I have this issue:
 my website has multilpe subdomains, ( 'www.example.com', 'bla1.example.com', 'bla2.example.com', ... ) and until now i was using a wildcard certificate like " *.example.com" with this apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName example.com
 ServerAlias *.example.com
 ...
 ... 
 ...
 SSLEngine on
 SSLProxyEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile ssl/*.example.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile ssl/*.example.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile ssl/chain

</VirtualHost>
```

but now i need on some domains an different type of certificate and my question is this.
How can i use a condition like in the example below ?:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName example.com
 ServerAlias *.example.com
 ...
 ... 
 ...
 SSLEngine on
 SSLProxyEngine on

<If "%{HTTP_HOST} in { 'www.exanple.com', 'bala2.example.com' }" >
 SSLCertificateFile ssl/certL3.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile ssl/certL3.key
</If>
<Else>
 SSLCertificateFile ssl/*.example.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile ssl/*.example.key
</Else>
 SSLCertificateChainFile ssl/chain

</VirtualHost>
```

This example does not work, i receive this error message: SSLCertificateFile not allowed here

Comment: You cannot use different certificates inside a single http host, obviously. You _can_ however setup different hosts within the same http server which allows to use different certificates per host.

Comment: I have a similar setup  with a non wildcard that works perfectly, example:

     <VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerName example.com
       ServerAlias *.example.com
       ...
       ... 
       ...
       SSLEngine on
       SSLProxyEngine on

       SSLCertificateFile ssl/www.example.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile ssl/www.example.key

       SSLCertificateFile ssl/bla1.example.crt
       SSLCertificateKeyFile ssl/bla1.example.key

       SSLCertificateChainFile ssl/chain

      </VirtualHost>

Comment: FYI wildcard certificates are not supported or accepted by all browsers.  For internal use (ex. dev environment) it might be ok, but certainly not for live sites.  Chrome is one that does not play well with wildcard certs.  We got rid of them where I work.  Better to use 1 certificate with `alt_names` defined.